# How to use variable in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm having problem to use variable in ng-repeat and javascript part.

How can i pass variable (x.name) to javascript in same block?

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="x in users" modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html', { param1: '{{ x.name }}', animation : 'slide' } );">
```

I already tried these usages below :

param1: '{{ x.name }}'

param1: '"+{{ x.name }}+"'

param1: '"+ x.name +"'

But no luck?

Thank you

Comment: Angular can parse all the code inside `ng-xxxxx` directives without `{{ }}` template

Answer (score 2):

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="x in users" modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html', { param1:  x.name , animation : 'slide' } );">
```

Just use `param1:  x.name`

Comment: I thought so as well, but why this doesn't work then https://jsfiddle.net/gz96xz8j/1/

Comment: @SlavenTomac the ng-click is looking for console in your scope. It would work if you did this: https://jsfiddle.net/wpfy8ua4/

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. Can you help me with one similar problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gz96xz8j/2/. When I need to generate url to go to, it seems it doesn't recognize user.name.

Comment: @SlavenTomac For this you need to use {{}} https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref